# Can a shutdown (but still plugged) Raspberry Pi damage the TV?

Tags: kodi

Related to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/should-i-leave-the-raspberry-pi-plugged-in-after-shutdown), but the Raspberry Pi (specifically, Pi 3 Model B) is connected to LG TV through HDMI.

At the same time, the TV is also connected to a cable setup box (some sort of custom Android) through HDMI. In summary, the TV is switched off at night, but still connected to the RPi (shutdown but plugged) and setup box (always on).

**Can a shutdown (but still plugged) Raspberry Pi damage the TV? (regardless whether the TV is on/off)**

I'm asking this because the TV suddenly refuses to turn on today (the LED indicator is on with red colour, but nothing on the screen). I'm trying to pinpoint the culprit, whether it's the RPi, or the setup box (or both), or other thing (e.g. age).

Comment: The question you've asked is somewhat hypothetical and maybe too broad to answer. In a normal operating environment no the Pi won't damage the TV. However, talking hypothetically - lets say something is wrong and somehow the Pi delivers high voltage to the TV via it's HDMI then yes damage may occur. I's start by disconnecting all devices and see if the TV works, then reconnect each device one-at-a-time and see if you can pinpoint the issue. Perhaps it's a hardware fault of the TV.

Comment: @mintyfreshpenguin agreed! + I recommended removing the power of the TV (by unplugging the power cord), and letting it unpowered for 2-3 minutes.

Comment: A powered-off device certainly wouldn't be the first culprit I'd look to.

Comment: @mintyfreshpenguin it's actually happening now. If you can edit, could you edit the question, or point me what I should change?