# Drawing 0.6A from one usb port on Pi3?

Tags: usb-power, pi-3

I just got my Raspberry Pi 3 and I am not sure whether or not I can draw 0.6A from ONE USB port (others unused (keyboard and mouse excluded)). Can the RPI handle this? Can I use all slots at once for devices that require 0.6A?

Comment: Did you do some research? I just found a very helpful forum thread here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/340/how-much-power-can-be-provided-through-usb

Comment: @Michielvk: To be fair, there have been substantial hardware changes since then. I wouldn't necessarily call this a duplicate.

Comment: @Michielvk that may not be accurate for the Pi3 which claims to have better power management, and was designed for power hungry devices (WiiFI and HDD).

Comment: I just realised it was an old model on the forum sorry.

Comment: At the RPI site faq at the Power chapter is some info also for the more recent RPI (2B) https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is NO ONE can answer this question (due to the lack of published data by Broadcom).

If the hub complies with the USB standard the answer is NO. Many hubs do not, and will supply as much as you want (although often with a non compliant voltage drop).

The Pi can supply TOTAL 600mA from USB, although this can be increased to 1.2A.