# Powering HDMI splitter from Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: hdmi, power-supply

I have a base zero W that I want to turn into a receiver for spotify connect and some old speakers that connect via a 3.5mm jack.

I want to get audio out of it that isn't horrific sounding (such as $5 USB to 3.5mm DAC) but doesn't have to be stellar. I have an existing HDMI splitter that outputs a hdmi signal to hdmi/spdif/and analog stereo. Since I have this already and the sound is fine, I thought it was worth starting here.

**Firstly** I need confirmation that if I run a micro-HDMI cable to this splitter, that I will be able to split analog audio from it? I guess the question is whether there's any hurdles in getting audio as expected from the micro-HDMI port of a zeroW or will I need to do anything further? In my research I saw a possibility i may need to edit a config file.

**Secondly** The HDMI splitter is powered over DC via a micro USB jack. I doubt that the USB power from the zero W output is enough to power this but thought I would check. This should be a simple comparison of specs but I can never quite confidently understand this stuff.

The HDMI splitter says its max working current is 190mA and standby power is 5V/500mA. [From my research](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/342/126026), is it as simple as saying 190mA and 500mA are both higher than 100mA (the most power that should be drawn) so it's a straightforward no unless I want to rewire stuff (which I don't)?

I'm unsure if 100mA applies to the zero W. On the other hand, [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3zyhuq/pi_zero_usb_power_outputmilliamps/) suggests the output is only limited by the input into the zero W but to be careful. I'm using the official UK power adapter for the zero W (5.1v/2.5a).

---

I suppose an unusual caveat here that goes against the grain is that I'm not particularly technically-minded or interested in tinkering or DIY. The idea of having two power plugs for this project (the pi doesn't have any usb power source nearby) is off-putting enough to reconsider it. As is soldering, custom cases, or going beyond editing config files. I'm inept at these and always seem to break things. I also need a neat, small solution and an oversized box or exposed wires is going to get complaints in the house from others (so adding a hat or board that breaks it out of the tiny standard case is not a simple solution for me).

Obviously I'm the sort of person who should be looking for a small chromecast etc. It just feels a shame to waste the zero W while I'm looking at adding another spotify connect point. I completely understand the lack of empathy coming from a raspberry pi forum for someone like me!

Comment: I'm also pretty new to electronics and stuff, so I can't answer much of your question, but according to this thread, the USB on the Zero is connected straight to DC input on the pi, so the current drawn form the USB port is only limited by the power supply: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=159920 However, your sources say that there are fuses that blow if the current is over 140mA, so it'd be great to have someone clarify that. But theoretically, you're correct in thinking that a power supply must have a max. current rating above or equal to the current that the device draws.

Comment: Edit - I missed the line in your post saying that the current is limited by the power supply, so yeah... I'm not personally sure, maybe ask the same question but explain that some say that it's limited by a fuse and others say that it is not.